# Filtering Multiple Operation in angularJs

Tags: angularjs

I have to filter based on two values. I am trying with following functionality

JSON data is,

```
{"homeAddress":"26, New Street, Bangalore",
        "officeAddress":"31, Old Office Street, Bangalore"
},{
"homeAddress":"27, Neww Street, Bangalore",
        "officeAddress":"30, Old Office Street, Bangalore"
}


        var locationFilter = {officeAddress: location};
        var locationFilter1 = {homeAddress: location};
        filterData = $filter('filter')(data, locationFilter);
        filterData = $filter('filter')(data, locationFilter1);
        return filterData;
```

By using above functionality. It have filtered second option only.

So how to filter with the two condition with the above styling and how can i use OR, AND Opeartion in this.

When i filtering For ex: 26 & 31 is filter correctly. But here 27 is not filtering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `AND` functionality (i.e., when you want to show only the elements that have both `officeAddress` and `homeAddress` equal to `location`), just create a combined object and pass it into `filter`:

```
var bothLocationsCheck = {
  officeAddress: location,
  homeAddress: location
};
filterData = $filter('filter')(data, bothLocationsCheck);
```

That'll obviously give you 'AND'; for 'OR', just concat two results:

```
filteredData = $filter('filter')(data, locationFilter).concat(
  $filter('filter')(data, locationFilter1));
```

... but in this case you'll have to remove the duplicates from the result.

Still, I'd prefer another approach: implementing this kind of operations within filtering function itself. For example:

```
filteredData = $filter('filter')(data, function(el) {
  return el.homeAddress.indexOf(location) !== -1  
      || el.officeAddress.indexOf(location) !== -1
});
```

It's rather trivial to change this function from `OR` to `AND` functionality.

Comment: I have to use OR Operation. But it may give AND Operation

Comment: Could you be more specific about which of those `not working` in your case?

Comment: Data has filtered from officeAddress but not in homeAddress